# Object behind glass appear dark in AMD Pro Renderer

Tags: rendering, radeon-prorender-render-engine

I am trying to create a beer glass with the liquid inside. I am not sure why the liquid becomes darker when the glass is rendered. Without the glass the color is much brighter.
[image: example]

[image]

Comment: Try going to render -> light paths and increasing transmission and glossy bounces

Comment: In render I have the max ray depth set to 10. Glossy, refraction and glossy refraction set to 10 too. Still get the same thing. Not sure what my issue is.